# Number of permutation with repetition in Python?

Tags: python, python-itertools

is there a function to calculate the number of permutations with repetition in Python? I know with itertools I can generate them but I want only a faster way to do the calculation and avoid calculating the factorials, I'm not interested in generating all possible permutations.

Example: calculate the possible strings composed by 4 As, 3 Bs, 5 Cs.

res= 12!/(4!3!5!)

or in code:

```
from math import factorial
from functools import reduce
rep=[4,3,5]
result= factorial(sum(rep))//reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, map(factorial, rep))
```

Comment: You got 2 options, either you generate them and count them, either you use the formula which gives you the number. If you don't want any of them, well you can't do anything. What is wrong with the 4 lines of code you used? Just create your own function.

Comment: There is still the option of building a lookup table for factorials. You do all the processing once (it can be outside of your script) to generate the table then move the needle in your table to get the results.

Comment: No problem with my code, I need to apply it with big numbers and I was looking for the possibility to use some function with better optimization.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't really a faster way. One optimization would be to avoid computing `factorial(max(rep))` and when you compute `factorial(sum(rep))` only do the product of the numbers bigger than `max(rep)`. However implementing this as a new python function will be slower than just using `factorial` for sure.

Comment: Giacomo, I opened this question to find out if function like the one you are proposing has been prepared in some package. If I try to implement that in Python I'm sure I cannot make it faster than factorial

Comment: What kind of inputs is this approach too slow for?

Comment: the case that made me look into this topic was rep=[15000000,2] , very big number with extreme difference: the simplified version  would be a easy multiplication 15000000*14999999/2 . But those are very extreme cases